# Why this lemma is true?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, automata

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet of size $|\Sigma|=k$. Let $w\in\Sigma^*$ be a word over $\Sigma$. If $|w| > 2^k$, then $w$ contains an infix $y$ with $|y|\ge 2$, such that every letter occurring in y occurs an even number of times in $y$.

Seems it's obvious but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the pigeonhole principle, there must be two different prefixes of $w$ that contain the same number of each letter modulo 2. Their difference is your $y$.

Comment: Oh yes thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this should be a comment to Henning's answer, but I think there is still a crucial point of the reasoning to be explained, namely...

For each prefix of x associate a k-tuple over {0,1} that represents the parity of each of the k letters in that prefix.  Obviously, there are only $2^k$ such binary k-tuples possible, so if there are $2^k+1$ letters in x, one of the k-tuples must repeat at two different prefixes -- there's the pigeonhole principle.  The points at which they repeat give Henning's two prefixes in which the parity of each letter is the same.